# SQL Server distribution agent cleanup job causes blocking

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, transactional-replication

I am using SQL Server transactional replication, and have noticed that on a daily basis all of the publications for a distributor are being blocked when the distribution agent cleanup job executes.  I have seen this block persist for up to 2 hours.  Some of the subscriptions require extremely low latency, so this is a big problem for me right now.

I have read that setting the HistoryVerboseLevel to 0 will stop logging to MSdistribution_history database.  Having done this, the blocking subsided for the subscriptions that i changed the distributor profiles for.  However, within three days all of the subscriptions were marked inactive.

I'm out of ideas at this point, so was hoping that someone else has a solution.  My next step is try enabling snapshot isolation on the distribution database, but feel that this is a "sledge hammer" approach.

Comment: What does sp_helpdistributor return for min distrib retention and max distrib retention?

Comment: Also, what is the publication property value immediate_sync set to?

Comment: Hi Brandon, thanks for responding.  Min distrib retention = 0, max distrib retention = 48, immediate_sync = 0

Comment: What does sp_helppublication return for retention? Does it return 0?  USE PubDB EXEC sp_helppublication @publication = 'PublicationName'

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply, wife and 1 kiddo have the flu ... tough day.  Retention = 0 for the pub.

Comment: I suspect the MSrepl_commands table is very large as well.  Your scenario sounds similar to the one described here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1823/troubleshooting-slow-sql-server-replication-issue-due-to-distributor-database-growth/

Comment: You may want to try temporarily changing the retention to 120, manually run the distribution agent cleanup job, and see if that reduces the size of MSrepl_commands.  This should speed up subsequent distribution cleanup job runs.

Comment: I am also aware of a distribution cleanup job bug that will occur in certain versions of SQL Server.  I have detailed one here:  https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/725860/sp-msdistribution-cleanup-fails-to-remove-all-delivered-transactions#details

Comment: thanks, you are spot on with your articles and findings.  I'm going to double check the solution tomorrow, and will mark this as the answer at that time!!